# Ejemplo en React, dos flechas consecutivas al definir una función flecha

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy tratando de entender un código de ejemplo de uso de React, pero se me complicó.

Estoy medio mareado, confundido, perdido o todo eso junto.

No entiendo el uso de la doble flecha el la implementación de onClick:

```
  const onClick  = item => () => { 
                                   onSelect(item.key)
                                 }`
```

Como se ve en el código, primero hay una flecha luego de "item", después le siguen los paréntesis vacíos que indicarían que no hay argumentos en la función flecha, pero de la función flecha que se construiría con la flecha de más a la derecha.

Mi pregunta es: ¿no se podría suprimir los paréntesis y una de las flechas como en el siguiente código?

```
  const onClick  = item => { 
                             onSelect(item.key)
                           }
```

Obviamente lo probé y no funcionó.

Como otra prueba, en el código original, encerré entre paréntesis todo lo que aparece luego de la primer flecha:

```
  const onClick  = item => ( () => { 
                                    onSelect(item.key)
                                   } )
```

Esto teniendo la sospecha de que posiblemente, la función flecha ahora encerrada entre paréntesis, regresara un objeto.
Esto último si funcionó, pero no puedo darle una explicación formal.

¿Alguno podría darme un indicio o explicación de porqué fue hecho así?

Saludos a todos y gracias de antemano.

El código completo del ejemplo es el siguiente:

```
const menus = [
  { key: 'home', label: 'Home' },
  { key: 'product', label: 'Product' },
  { key: 'about', label: 'About' },
  { key: 'secure', label: 'Secure', disabled: true },
]



const Nav = ({ items, selected, onSelect }) => {
  const isActive = item => item.key === selected
  const onClick  = item => () => { 
                                   onSelect(item.key)
                                 }

  return (
    <ul>
      {items.map(item => (
        <li
          key={item.key}
          className={isActive(item) ? 'active' : ''}
        >
          <button
            disabled={item.disabled}
            onClick={onClick(item)}
          >
            {item.label}
          </button>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  )
}


const Home = () => <h1>Home page</h1>
const Product = () => <h1>Product page</h1>



const Route = ({ selected }) => {
    return (
      <div>
      {selected === 'home' && <Home />}
      {selected === 'product' && <Product />}
    </div>
    )
}



let m = undefined

function _getM(initialValue) {
  if (m === undefined) {
    m = initialValue
  }
  
  return m
}

function _setM(value) { 
  m = value
  ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootEl)
}



const App = () => {
  const selected = _getM("home")
  
  return ( 
    <div>
      <Nav
        items={menus} 
        selected={selected} 
        onSelect={_setM} 
      />
      <Route selected={selected} />
    </div>
  )
}


const rootEl =
  document.getElementById('root')

ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootEl)
```

Answer (score 2):

El uso de una doble flecha en React se utiliza para crear una función de orden superior (*Higher Order Function* o *HOF*). Esto significa que la primera flecha es para definir una función que devuelve otra función, y la segunda flecha es para la función que se devuelve.

En el ejemplo que presentas, `onClick` es una función que se ejecuta cuando se hace clic en el botón y, por tanto, es un callback que se pasa a la propiedad `onClick` de un componente de botón. El propósito de esta función es ejecutar `onSelect` con la clave del elemento de menú seleccionado, por lo que `onSelect` sabe qué elemento está seleccionado.

La razón por la que se utilizan dos flechas es porque `onClick` debe recibir un argumento (el elemento del menú seleccionado) para que pueda pasar esa información a `onSelect`. La primera flecha crea una función que espera un argumento (el elemento del menú seleccionado), y la segunda flecha devuelve una función que, cuando se ejecuta, llama a `onSelect` con el elemento del menú seleccionado.

El siguiente código es equivalente a la versión de dos flechas:

```
const onClick  = item => { 
  return () => { 
    onSelect(item.key)
  }
}
```

Aquí, la primera flecha se utiliza para crear una función que espera un argumento, al igual que en el ejemplo original, y la segunda flecha se utiliza para devolver la función que se ejecutará cuando se haga clic en el botón.

En cuanto a la versión de dos paréntesis, lo que está sucediendo es que se está creando una función que devuelve otra función. Es decir, `onClick` sigue siendo una función de orden superior, pero en lugar de utilizar dos flechas, se están utilizando dos pares de paréntesis. Los paréntesis más internos crean una función que espera un argumento, y los paréntesis más externos devuelven esa función.

En general, la forma de dos flechas es una forma común en `React` de crear funciones de orden superior. Pero también puedes usar dos pares de paréntesis o la sintaxis tradicional de una sola flecha con un cuerpo de función explícito para lograr el mismo resultado. Todo dependerá de cuál de las opciones resulte más clara para ti.